# IndexError: list index out of range in tksheet tkinter

Tags: tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk  
import tksheet
top = tk.Tk()     
sheet = tksheet.Sheet(top)
sheet.grid()
tmin=10
tmax=100
incr=10
ran=int((tmax-tmin)/incr)
for i in range(ran):
   d=2*(i+1)
   c=2*d
```

sheet.set_sheet_data([d][c])

I got error
line 20, in 
sheet.set_sheet_data([d][c])
IndexError: list index out of range
why this error is presented
how to fix this error

I got error
line 20, in 
sheet.set_sheet_data([d][c])
IndexError: list index out of range
why this error is presented
how to fix this error

Comment: What do you want to do on the problem line `sheet.set_sheet_data([d][c])` actually?

Comment: I want to add these values to be displayed as first and second column values in table

Comment: i want to add values of c function on first column and the values of d in second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description in your comment, what you need is to create a 2-D list using the for loop and then use `sheet.set_sheet_data()` to set the table data:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tksheet

top = tk.Tk()

sheet = tksheet.Sheet(top)
sheet.grid()

tmin = 10
tmax = 100
incr = 10

ran = int((tmax - tmin) / incr)
# create the table data
data = []
for i in range(ran):
    d = 2 * (i + 1)
    c = 2 * d
    data.append([c, d])
# set the table data of the sheet
sheet.set_sheet_data(data)

top.mainloop()
```